# How do I properly remove an item from ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

I am having problem while removing item from ListView,

This is my Activity :

```
public class TestListItemsView1Activity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private EfficientAdapter efficientAdapter;
    private String[] data = new String[] { "BBC", "Yahoo", "CNN", "Eenadu", "Hindu" };
    private List<String> dataValues = Arrays.asList(data);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        efficientAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this,dataValues);

        setListAdapter(efficientAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        //dataValues.remove(position);
        //efficientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click-" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and the Adapter class:

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static String TAG=EfficientAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;

    private HashMap<String,EfficientAdapter.ViewHolder> holders= new HashMap<String, EfficientAdapter.ViewHolder>();
    //private String[] dataArray = new String[] { "BBC", "Yahoo", "CNN", "Eenadu", "Hindu" };
    private List<String> data= new ArrayList<String>();//Arrays.asList(dataArray);

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context,List<String> data) {
        //super(context, R.layout.main, values);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context=context;
        this.data.addAll(data);
    }

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        //super(context, R.layout.main, values);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context=context;
        //data.addAll(data);
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLine);
            holder.buttonLine =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);

            holder.textLine.setText(this.data.get(position));
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos= position;
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                }
            });

            holder.buttonLine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                private int pos= position;

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    /*ViewHolder deleteHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
                    int delPosition=deleteHolder.position;
                    holders.remove(delPosition);
                    ViewHolder currentHolder;
                    for(int i=pos+1;i<getCount();i++){
                        currentHolder = holders.get(delPosition);
                        currentHolder.position=i-1;
                    }
                    data.remove(delPosition);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();*/
                    //View convertView1 = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);
//                  ViewHolder deleteHolder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

                    data.remove(getItem(pos));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


                    //final ArrayAdapter adapter = ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter());


                    //ListView lv = v.findViewById(R.layout.)


                    //v.invalidate();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Delete button pressed at position" + pos);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Delete-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            //holder.position=position;
            //holders.put(Integer.toString(position), holder);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textLine;
        ImageView iconLine;
        Button buttonLine;
        //int position;
        }

}
```

Every time its removing last item not the one which clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter code here`I think you are no updating the position of the View.

When you did `if (convertView == null) { inflate........}` you're saying that the first time the View is created, must do this. But in Android Views in ListViews are reusables, so if you need to update the position of the view, you must put out of this Conditional.

Try to set de ClickLsiteners out of the `if (convertView = null)`...in the else.
Try it... and tell me

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private static String TAG=EfficientAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Context context;

//private String[] dataArray = new String[] { "BBC", "Yahoo", "CNN", "Eenadu", "Hindu" };
private List<String> data= new ArrayList<String>();

public EfficientAdapter(Context context,List<String> data) {
    super();
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context=context;
    this.data.addAll(data);
}

public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    super();
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context=context;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLine);
        holder.buttonLine =(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.textLine.setText(getItem(position));
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }
    });
    holder.buttonLine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i(TAG, "Delete button pressed at position" + position);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete-" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}


public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textLine;
    ImageView iconLine;
    Button buttonLine;
    //int position;
}

@Override
public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
    return null;
}
```

}

is working! test it :)

Comment: Have moved to else condition but still same

Comment: What about add on the Activity an OnClickItemListener and then call `adapter.remove(int position)`. You must create this method in the adapter as public and do `data.remove(position)`. What about that?